# Pascal Repeating a Program Untill A String Variable is Empty

Tags: pascal

So I'm Writing a program for pascal and it is asking me to repeat that program until the no name is entered [This Is the exact question if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0MLT.png)

So I found out the meaning for null/empty in pascal is `''` I tried different codes this is the last one I tried

```
program Lunch;
Const
  Dues_Percentage1=0.3;
    Dues_Percentage2=0.2;
    Var
      Name:String;
      Age:Integer;
      Lunch_Money:Real;
      Dues:Real;
begin
  While Name <> '' Do
  Writeln('Please Enter Your Name');
  Read(Name);
  Writeln('Please Enter Your Age');
  Read(Age);
  Writeln('Please Enter The Amount of Money You Receive');
  Read(Lunch_Money);
  If Age >10 then
  Dues:= Lunch_Money*Dues_Percentage1
  else
  Dues:= Lunch_Money*Dues_Percentage2;
  Writeln('The Amount Of Lunch Money You Receive is $',Lunch_Money:4:2);
  WriteLn('The Amount Of Dues You will pay Is $',Dues:3:2);
  Readln(Dues,Lunch_Money);
end.
```

And it doesn't work I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: `And it doesn't work` isn't very precise. You may want to read up on `begin..end` compound statements.

Comment: my bad on that when i saw it doesn't work what i mean is the program itself doesn't repeat itself as it should regardless if I enter a name or leave it blank and i'm not sure what you mean by begin end compund statements

Comment: `while ... do` only repeats the statement that follows immediately. If you want multiple statements to repeat you must enclose them in `begin..end`, so e.g. `while Name <> '' do begin writeln(...; read(..); end;`.

Comment: Ok I see let me try it out I guess sorry for the late replies I've been sleeping

Comment: What if I had Used a Repeat Until statement with the same condition? Would that work?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but `while` with `begin..end` is fine too.

Comment: I really wanna thank you for your suggestion. I understood what you said about the begin and end and i read it up and made changes according. It repeats now but it does not close when i have a blank name but you were of such help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you use a while loop, you need to initialise "Name" before you make the test (and then read it before each next test within the loop). For example:

```
 var
   Name : string;
 begin
   //Initialise Name
   readln(Name);
   while Name <> '' do
   begin
     // do stuff here
     // and here
     //then read the next name
     readln(Name);
   end;
 end;
```

Note that while only carries out the next statement (if the condition is true), so you need to use a compound statement if you want the while to do more than just one statement.

If you use a repeat until you may need a slightly different structure:

```
 var
   Name : string;
 begin
   repeat
     readln(Name);
     if Name <> '' then
     begin
        // do stuff here
        // and here
     end;
   until Name = '';
 end;
```

Comment: Thanks broski but I already got the answer :D Thanks anyway tho